# Set xlink:href in svg with angularjs to base64-encoded image

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, svg

I'm making something like project-specific svg online editor, and want to add ability to load file from computer, which will be encoded in base64 and set as svg `fill` background.

Problem: when I set correct base64 as image xlink:href through angularjs I doesn't see it as background (tested in Safari 8.0.8). All works fine if I set image href as inlined base64 or remote url.

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/nk71b3jt/1/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first thing here is that `ng-attrs-xlink:href` won't bind to `xlink:href`, it will be normalized it to `xlink-href`.

Fortunately, Angular already [does that](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.2.28/src/ng/directive/booleanAttrs.js#L377) for `ng-href` directive.

The second is that Angular sucks at many things specific to DOM, including this [SVG-related one](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/7697). `xlink:href` will be added by `ng-href` but it just won't work. The workaround is to have empty `xlink:href` attribute on the element, so Angular doesn't have to create it.

Here is [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a4amd36L/).

Comment: Solution worked. Cheers:

<image ng-href="{{profileImage}}" xlink:href="" x="249" y="280" height="80px" width="80px" clip-path="url(#myClip)"/>